# How to detect changed rows according to the effective and expiry dates in SQL (preferably Bigquery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am stuck with a situation on sql. I have a table like this in BigQuery:

```
row - supplier_id - cargo_provider  - rate - effective_date - expiry date

1   - 1001        - cp1             - 30   - 2021.01.01     - 2021.01.15
2   - 1001        - cp2             - 70   - 2021.01.01     - 2021.01.15
3   - 1001        - cp1             - 30   - 2021.01.15     - 2021.01.20
4   - 1001        - cp2             - 70   - 2021.01.15     - 2021.01.20
5   - 1001        - cp1             - 50   - 2021.01.20     - 9999.01.01
6   - 1001        - cp3             - 50   - 2021.01.20     - 9999.01.01
```

Then, my aim is to keep only change logs of supplier's cargo provider or rate of the cargo provider on the table. I need a control mechanism to delete if there is no change (between 2021.01.15 and 2021.01.20) in 3rd and 4th rows by comparing with the previous situation (2021.01.01 and 2021.01.15) and delete from the table. And this mechanism should also detect that even the cargo provider is the same rate is different in 5th row and a new cargo provider(cp3) is changed with cp2, so there is a change between 2021.01.20 and 9999.01.01(this means this rate and cargo provider are still valid).
Finally, my target table should like:

```
row - supplier_id - cargo_provider  - rate - effective_date - expiry date

1   - 1001        - cp1             - 30   - 2021.01.01     - 2021.01.20 (not 2021.01.15)
2   - 1001        - cp2             - 70   - 2021.01.01     - 2021.01.20 (not 2021.01.15)
3   - 1001        - cp1             - 50   - 2021.01.20     - 9999.01.01
4   - 1001        - cp3             - 50   - 2021.01.20     - 9999.01.01
```

I couldn't find a way to do it in sql but is there anyone who can do this or give a way to do.

I am using Bigquery but anyy SQL language is okey for me. I can change it to bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You are looking for periods of time where the rate is the same on adjacent rows, where adjacency seems to be defined by the expiry date matching the next effective date.

For this version, you can use `lag()` to see when an "island" starts.  That is, there is no gap in the rate.  A cumulative sum of the "island starts" defines each "island".  The rest is aggregation.

```
select supplier_id, cargo_provider, rate,
       min(effective_date), max(expiry_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_expiry_date = effective_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by supplier_id, cargo_provider, rate order by effective_date) as island
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(expiry_date) over (partition by supplier_id, cargo_provider, rate order by effective_date) as prev_expiry_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by supplier_id, cargo_provider, rate, island
```